# How to delay a set of instructions in a jquery while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show three pictures at a time on the screen. I have the sources of my pictures saved in an array and I will keep taking three random pictures from this array, remove them from the array, show them on the screen for an amount of time and then replace them with the next set of 3 pictures until I will ran out of pictures.

I can't figure what is the problem.

I have copied the code here:

### JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start').click(function () {
        "use strict";
        $(this).fadeOut(400);
        $('#start').remove();
        var $arrayOfPicSrc = ["p1.jpg", "p2.jpg", "p3.jpg", "p1.jpg", "p2.jpg", "p3.jpg"];
        var randomNumber;
        var $picturesToPrint;
        var i;
        while ($arrayOfPicSrc.length > 0) {
            $picturesToPrint = [];
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
                randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * $arrayOfPicSrc.length) - 1;
                $picturesToPrint.push($arrayOfPicSrc[randomNumber]);
                $arrayOfPicSrc.splice(randomNumber, 1);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
                $('body').append("<img class='toRemove' src=" + $picturesToPrint[i] + " height='100px' width='100'>");
            }
            $('.toRemove').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('.toRemove').remove();
            });
            $picturesToPrint.splice(0, 3);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is a link with the JS and the HTML I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lgpx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing delaying your FOR loop within your WHILE loop from executing immediately, so all images are appended at once, then are faded out after a 3 second delay. The delay(3000) does not delay like in synchronous coding; it only delays the next item that follows it in the queue (fadeOut).

Take a look at the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions. Using `setInterval` you can replace your photos every x seconds.

Updated fiddle, which I think gets at what you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Khj8m/